# Magento using addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection returns nothing when it shouldn't

Tags: magento, collections, report, visibility, product

In Magento I'm using the following code to get a bestsellers data collection:

Model Function:

```
  public function bestSellers($limit = 12){

    $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addOrderedQty()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('id')
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc') //best sellers on top
        ->setPageSize($limit); 

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($_productCollection);

    return $_productCollection; 

}
```

Block Output:

```
<?php $products = Mage::getModel('tabs/collections')->bestSellers($limit); ?>
<pre>
    <?php print_r($productCollection->getData()); ?>
</pre>
```

However it returns nothing when the addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection line is used in the model function, but if I remove the addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection line, then it returns an array of expected bestselling product data (including the ones that shouldn't be visible in the catalog).

How can I return my array of data with the visibility filter working as it should? Rather than returning nothing. Very confused. Thanks in advance!

Here's the getSelect:

```
   SELECT SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) AS `ordered_qty`, `order_items`.`name` AS `order_items_name`, `order_items`.`product_id` AS `entity_id`, `e`.`entity_type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`updated_at`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position` FROM `sales_flat_order_item` AS `order_items`
  INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `order` ON `order`.entity_id = order_items.order_id AND `order`.state <> 'canceled'
  LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON (e.type_id NOT IN ('grouped', 'configurable', 'bundle')) AND e.entity_id = order_items.product_id AND e.entity_type_id = 4
  INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='2' WHERE (parent_item_id IS NULL) GROUP BY `order_items`.`product_id` HAVING (SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) > 0) ORDER BY `ordered_qty` desc
```

Comment: This code works for me... Try disabling 3rd party modules, what magento version is this on?

Comment: Using Magento CE v1.6.2.0 with Flat Product Catalog enabled. Same as yours?

Comment: I believe I had flat catalog disabled on the install I tried it on (same CE version) - does it make any difference when you disable it? what is the output of echo $productCollection->getSelect(); ?

Comment: It returns a Varien_Db_Select Object with lots of random stuff to do with the sales flat order table. Not the data I need though. When I disable flat catalog I get the following error:
 Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816

Comment: Now try what I actually said (echo).

Comment: Apologies I misread your question above! I've added it to my post above ^^

Comment: If I run the above select statement in SQL, it indeed doesn't return any results. But if I run the SQL it generates with that addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection line commented out, it returns lots of results (including products that shouldn't be visible).

Comment: Refreshing the indexes resolved the issue of not returning any products! However it doesn't return the configurable products (as a parent product), whilst using this visibility filter. Any ideas? (see my comment on the post below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my Block which i use to obtain bestsellers. It also does simple products that are variants of parental configurable products, to configurable products (works correctly only if one simple products is assigned to max 1 configurable product): http://devblog.fishol.pl/bestselling-products-in-magento/

Comment: You wouldn't be able to share that code from the broken link would you? My code is not returning simple products from configurables.

Answer (score 2):

I think it happens because `addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection()` does more than you can think of. Let's look at it's code `(app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility.php, line 66)`:

```
public function addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection(Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract $collection)
{
    $collection->setVisibility($this->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
```

//        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('in'=>$this->getVisibleInCatalogIds()));
        return $this;
    }

Now, let's look at `$collection->setVisibility($this->getVisibleInCatalogIds())` closely. Let's go to `\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Collection.php`:

```
public function setVisibility($visibility)
{
    $this->_productLimitationFilters['visibility'] = $visibility;
    $this->_applyProductLimitations();

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Apply limitation filters to collection
 * Method allows using one time category product index table (or product website table)
 * for different combinations of store_id/category_id/visibility filter states
 * Method supports multiple changes in one collection object for this parameters
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
 */
protected function _applyProductLimitations()
{
    $this->_prepareProductLimitationFilters();
    $this->_productLimitationJoinWebsite();
    $this->_productLimitationJoinPrice();
    $filters = $this->_productLimitationFilters;

    if (!isset($filters['category_id']) && !isset($filters['visibility'])) {
        return $this;
    }

    $conditions = array(
        'cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id',
        $this->getConnection()->quoteInto('cat_index.store_id=?', $filters['store_id'])
    );
    if (isset($filters['visibility']) && !isset($filters['store_table'])) {
        $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()
            ->quoteInto('cat_index.visibility IN(?)', $filters['visibility']);
    }
    $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()
        ->quoteInto('cat_index.category_id=?', $filters['category_id']);
    if (isset($filters['category_is_anchor'])) {
        $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()
            ->quoteInto('cat_index.is_parent=?', $filters['category_is_anchor']);
    }

    $joinCond = join(' AND ', $conditions);
    $fromPart = $this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::FROM);
    if (isset($fromPart['cat_index'])) {
        $fromPart['cat_index']['joinCondition'] = $joinCond;
        $this->getSelect()->setPart(Zend_Db_Select::FROM, $fromPart);
    }
    else {
        $this->getSelect()->join(
            array('cat_index' => $this->getTable('catalog/category_product_index')),
            $joinCond,
            array('cat_index_position' => 'position')
        );
    }

    $this->_productLimitationJoinStore();

    Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_collection_apply_limitations_after', array(
        'collection'    => $this
    ));

    return $this;
}
```

So, as you can see, product should be assigned to current website and should be added to some category from current website to appear in the products collection. Also, there are some other requirements here, as you can see.

Comment: After refreshing my indexes I've got products back, woohoo! All products are assigned to category and a website. However it doesn't return any configurable products, when using the visibility filter.

The visiblity filter removes products which have been deleted, but also removes the configurable products as the individual bestselling options are obviously not visible individually.

Any ideas on how to return the configurable products (as the parent product) whilst not returning the deleted products from the system, whilst using the visibility filter of some description?

Answer (score 0):

Just for a future reference.

I've had very similar problem.

One of the widgets was not showing random products.

Because of

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);
```

Product have to be set visible for catalog (product -> visibility -> catalog, searching).